# Query a RealmList<Integer> with a parameter

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

My model is a Category, which has a list of parent id's.

```
private RealmList<Integer> parentCategories = new RealmList<>();
```

I need the subcategories from a given category.

My Query looked like this:

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[1];
intArray[0] = category.getId();

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realm.where(Category.class)
                .contains("parentCategories", category.getParentCategories())
                .findAll();
```

And I also tried this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmQuery<Category> query = realm.where(Category.class);
for (Integer id : category.getParentCategories()) {
     query.or().equalTo("id", id);
}
RealmResults<Category> results = query.findAll();
```

But both didn't work.
Could you point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: What I'm trying to do is not supported in a RealmQuery yet.
Thanks for pointing this out guys!

Comment: Is id of category and parentcategory the same?

Comment: Why isn't `parentCategories` a `RealmList<Category>`? What you are trying to do is not yet supported as a RealmQuery.

Comment: Because I just get a list of Integers from the backend, not full objects...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to query object list variables you need to use "in" -

```
String[] parentCategoriesArray = new String[]{"example"};

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm.where(Category.class)
            .in("parentCategories", parentCategoriesArray)
            .findAll();
```

Comment: The ID is an Integer. I get this exception:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'parentCategories' in class 'Category' is of invalid type 'INTEGER_LIST'.

Comment: `object list variables` ya, but primitives are not objects. So this is not yet supported unfortunately

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is right. you can use only object for now

Comment: @EpicPandaForce @nivm whats the workaround here? go back to querying `RealmList<RealmInteger>`?

Comment: my example, return which RealmObjects that have `RealmList<Integer>` contain at least one value of an array of Integers.

Comment: I think RealmList<RealmInteger> was always a bad idea, I always advocated using a single `String` field where you concat them together with a separator instead. It is literally the exact same approach as what you'd do in a relational db, when you don't want its own table for it.